# Getting Firefox 3 to work with JSUnit

Tags: javascript, caching, firefox-3, jsunit

Thus far this is what I've tried, I'm using Firefox 3.07

1. Make sure in **about:config** that the property **browser.cache.check_doc_frequency** is set to **1** which the browser interprets as "check for a new page every time".
2. Make sure in **about:config** that the property **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** is set to **false**.
3. When opening your browser be sure to specify to the **testrunner.html** page which test you want to run using the **testpage** parameter,
   I.E.: *file:///.../testRunner.html?testpage=c:/temp/someTest.html*
4. Tak an additional random parameter on the end to ensure that the cache is gone.

Everything above seems to work, except it is still *caching* my ***.js** files for some stupid reason.  I really thought it would have had to do with changing the random parameter at the end to kill the cache, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  What else can be done to make JSUnit work with Firefox 3.07? The files are located on my hdd.

Comment: Ah, this was actually dumb...I solved it.  I had two checked out directories that were both very much the same.  

I was in Eclipse and I didn't realize that I had been editing the wrong file all along.  STUPID! STUPID! STUPID!

Oh well it's not a total loss, now you all get to see how to fix ff3.

Comment: Kinda lame since it's the same content, but here's a blog post:
http://leeand00.tiddlyspot.com/#[[JSUnit%202.2%20on%20Firefox%203.07%20-%20FTW]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far this is what I've tried, I'm using Firefox 3.07

1.

```
  Make sure in about:config that the property browser.cache.check_doc_frequency is set to 1 which the browser interprets as "check for a new page every time".
```

2.

```
  Make sure in about:config that the property security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy is set to false.
```

3.

```
  When opening your browser be sure to specify to the testrunner.html page which test you want to run using the testpage parameter,

  I.E.: file:///.../testRunner.html?testpage=c:/temp/someTest.html
```

4.

```
  Tak an additional random parameter on the end to ensure that the cache is gone.
```

Everything above seems to work, except it is still caching my *.js files for some stupid reason. I really thought it would have had to do with changing the random parameter at the end to kill the cache, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. What else can be done to make JSUnit work with Firefox 3.07? The files are located on my hdd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CTRL + SHIFT + R to refresh without using cache?

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't work. The problem is that it is caching the *.js files. When you do CTRL + SHIFT + R it is only refreshing the test runner page.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the network.http.use-cache property in about:config.

e.g., network.http.use-cache = false

Answer (score 0):

Was pulling my hair out with same problem.

This finally worked for me:

Firefox Menu: Tools/Web Developer/Disable/Disable Cache